# 'length' is null or not an object in IE when using jQuery's inArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jkey

I'm using [jKey](https://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey) but in IE8 i'm getting this error:

`'length' is null or not an object`

Whenever i press certain keys. It seems like whenever i press a key that doesn't exist yet (like if i never set anything up for `a` it has the error message). But, I did setup a key command for `enter`, but it's still doing it.

The code in question that's causing the error is:

```
 if($.inArray(e.keyCode,keySplit[x]) > -1){
  // Initiate the active variable
  var active = 'unchecked';

  // All the individual keys in the combo with the keys that are currently being pressed
  for(y in keySplit[x]) {
   if(active != false) {
    if($.inArray(keySplit[x][y], activeKeys) > -1){
     active = true;
    }
    else {
     active = false;
    }
   }
  }
```

The error happens on the first line. Knowing that `keySplit[x]` returns a `typeof` `number` when nothing exists or if the key shortcut is only a single key, I added:

```
if(typeof(keySplit[x]) == 'number'){ keySplit[x] = [keySplit[x]]; }
```

Right above the code block above.

After that it sill worked in Chrome and FF, but still not IE. I also tried:

```
if(typeof(keySplit[x]) == 'number'){ keySplit[x] = new Array(keySplit[x]); }
if(typeof(keySplit[x]) == 'number'){ keySplit[x] = [keySplit[x].toString()]; }
if(typeof(keySplit[x]) == 'number'){ keySplit[x] = new Object(keySplit[x]); }
```

but none of them worked.The jQuery code that's causing the error is:

```
inArray: function( elem, array ) {

    if ( indexOf ) {
        return indexOf.call( array, elem );
    }

    for ( var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( array[ i ] === elem ) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your issue is related to **[another jKey bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066487/jkey-jquery-plugin-errors-in-ie6-7-attempting-to-run-whenever-any-un-used-key-i)**. Check please my **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066487/jkey-jquery-plugin-errors-in-ie6-7-attempting-to-run-whenever-any-un-used-key-i/7973383#7973383)** - you should use array like traversing in your implementation instead of associated.