# jKey jQuery plugin errors in IE6/7, attempting to run whenever any un-used key is pressed. How to combat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jkey

I'm using the jKey jQuery plugin on a current project. It just allows you to easily run a function on a key press. Here's my function call:

```
jQuery(document).jkey('left, right',function(key){
    if(key == 'left'){
        if (elementIndex == 0) { return; }
        question_nav(jQuery('.question-fieldset-active'), 'prev');
    } else {
        if ((elementIndex + 1) == jQuery('.question-fieldset').length) { return; }
        question_nav(jQuery('.question-fieldset-active'), 'next');
    }
});
```

In IE6 and 7, pressing any other key on the keyboard besides the left or right arrows throws a nasty "Error Message: 'indexOf' is null or not an object" error. Is there a way to capture all other key presses and return; on them so as to avoid this?

Comment: I'm the developer of jKey, does @ShankarSangoli answer below help? If not it might be some bug. I don't really support IE6 anymore, but I can take a look and see if i get the same error in IE8 or other browsers and if so correct it.

Comment: See if this code helps at all. I made some edits a few days ago. I dont have IE6/7 to test on at the moment, but let me know if it helps at all: https://gist.github.com/a8dadfc3b7b79c50b771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's bug of jKey itself. I've found this bug, when tried to use at the project. That was classic problem with looping through array as object:

*line 224*: `for(y in keySplit[x])` at **[GitHub revision](https://github.com/OscarGodson/jKey/blob/48873401c060bd57c7112abc4cb262a7af8ca998/jquery.jkey.js)**

The solution is to traverse array as traditional loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < keySplit.length; ++i)
```

So u can do it manually or get fixed version of 'jquery.jkey.js' from my **[Google Code revision](http://ajukraine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery/jquery.jkey.js)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using `else` condition check for `key == 'right'` as well that might help you.

```
jQuery(document).jkey('left, right',function(key){
    if(key == 'left'){
        if (elementIndex == 0) { return; }
        question_nav(jQuery('.question-fieldset-active'), 'prev');
    } else if(key == 'right') {
        if ((elementIndex + 1) == jQuery('.question-fieldset').length) { return; }
        question_nav(jQuery('.question-fieldset-active'), 'next');
    }
});
```